# Add Calculated Column into DF and Plot 2 Lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I start with the dataframe below, where each row is a new trial:

```
    test_group   range     success
0      test        1-5         1
1      test        1-5         0
2      test        1-5         1
3      test        6-10        1
4      test        6-10        0
5      test        6-10        0
6      control     1-5         0
7      control     1-5         0
8      control     1-5         1
9      control     6-10        1
10     control     6-10        1
11     control     6-10        1
```

I want to compute the mean success-value and group by test-group and range.

To do so, I'd write the following code:

```
df = df.groupby('test_group','range').success.mean()
```

My result looks like the following

```
test_group    range
test          1-5    0.66
              6-10   0.33
control       1-5    0.33
              6-10   1.00
```

Ideally, I want my final output to look like the following so that I can plot both test groups on the same chart, with the x-axis being each range and the y-axis being the success-rate:

```
 test_group   range     success-rate
0      test        1-5         0.66
1      test        1-5         0.66
2      test        1-5         0.66
3      test        6-10        0.33
4      test        6-10        0.33
5      test        6-10        0.33
6      control     1-5         0.33
7      control     1-5         0.33
8      control     1-5         0.33
9      control     6-10        1.00
10     control     6-10        1.00
11     control     6-10        1.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [transform()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) method:

```
In [35]: df['success-rate'] = df.groupby(['test_group','range'])['success'].transform('mean')

In [36]: df
Out[36]:
   test_group range  success  success-rate
0        test   1-5        1      0.666667
1        test   1-5        0      0.666667
2        test   1-5        1      0.666667
3        test  6-10        1      0.333333
4        test  6-10        0      0.333333
5        test  6-10        0      0.333333
6     control   1-5        0      0.333333
7     control   1-5        0      0.333333
8     control   1-5        1      0.333333
9     control  6-10        1      1.000000
10    control  6-10        1      1.000000
11    control  6-10        1      1.000000
```

`Groupby.transform()` method applies an aggregating function to **all** original  rows

Comment: Thanks, @MaxU! This is what I was looking for. Can you explain a bit what's happening under the hood?